# How to find duplicate names from table?

Tags: python, psql, peewee

I know we can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT > 1`. But this works when you have duplicate data. I have a little bit different data.

```
Id Names
1  Rahul S
2  Rohit S
3  Rishu
4  Sinu
5   Rahul S
6  Rohit  S
```

In the above table id 1 and 5 are same and 2 and 6 are also same. But when I use group by it count as different because of spaces. So how can I write a query with fuzzy logic something which will return these kind of duplicate datas.

**Update

Can someone help me with a query which will remove spaces from a particular column and add a imaginary column on that we can group by having count > 1

`SELECT replace(ltrim(rtrim(name)),' ','') as no_space FROM table GROUP BY no_space HAVING count(*) > 1 ORDER BY no_space;`

Comment: The correct word to use is `data normalization`:  clean up data due to input mistake, standardised case, etc.  Normalise during query are counter productive, it also render the index useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the spaces on selecting of the data?

Doing it this way ought to Cut the spaces in the string, and provide similar data. Take in mind that i mean removing double spaces and replacing it with 1 space, then doing a left and right trim on the data

Something like this :

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), '  ', ' ')
```

Just remember to include the having Count > 1

Comment: I have places where there is more than 1 or 2 or 3 spaces

Comment: Would it be an option to delete all spaces? Or will this lead to wrong matches? Is the first letter of every part capitalized? Then you could kill all the spaces and insert one defined new space before each capital letter...

Comment: we can delete all spaces

Comment: Hi. If you can delete all spaces i suggest doing the replace the same way but replace the 2 spaces with 1, and the 1 space with nothing like so :

Comment: REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), ' ', '')

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REPLACE function to remove white spaces.

I would save the string without spaces into a new column and use the group by on that.
Like:

```
Select <values you are looking for>, replace(Names, ' ', '') as d 
from <Table name> 
group by d
```

Comment: I have places where there is more than 1 or 2 or 3 spaces

Comment: `REPLACE` will be executed for each character, so it would transform ' Rahul          S ' to 'RahulS' regardless if the space is at the beginning or end or in the middle and regardless of how many spaces you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim
SELECT trim(name),trim(count(name)) FROM `tablename` group by trim(name)

Comment: Will TRIM will help if there is double spaces between first n last name

Answer (score 0):

I have created table and inserted your data.Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Emp;

CREATE TABLE Emp (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO Emp (Id, Name) VALUES
(1, 'Rahul S'), (2, 'Rohit S'), (3, 'Rishu'), (4, 'Sinu'), (5, ' Rahul S'),(5, 'Rohit  S');

    select * from Emp  Group by Name Having Name like '%Rohit%S%'
        Id  Name
1   5   Rohit  S
2   2   Rohit S
```

Query with wildcard  characters:

```
select * from Emp  Group by Name Having Name like '%_____%_%'

    Id  Name
1   5    Rahul S
2   1   Rahul S
3   5   Rohit  S
4   2   Rohit S
```